# phpMyAdmin MySQL CSV importing - get a warning if value is not in structure

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

When importing a CSV file into a MySQL database through phpMyAdmin, is there a way to get a warning if a value is not listed in the "values" list of a ENUM or SET field in the table's structure?

Right now, the value is dropped without a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me hours of trying various things, but I finally found the bizarre way that phpMyAdmin does warnings while importing csv data:

- For tables with up to **49** rows, phpMyAdmin reports warnings when data are truncated
- For tables with more rows, it does not

So, to see the warnings, I have to import the data piecemeal in chunks of 49 rows.

Answer (score 0):

some time mysql not support CSV.
So for data types then your need. SQL file import because sql file in sql data command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).